# HtmlAgilityPack cannot find specific td

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I need extract value of just one specific td from the table by using XPath, but code always return null. How can I fix this?

```
var location = GetLocation(document.Result.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='detailTabTable']/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"));
```

and the code

```
private string GetLocation(HtmlNode h)
        {
            try
            {
                string location = null;
                if (h == null)
                {
                    location = "N/A";
                }
                else
                {
                    location = h.InnerText;
                    location = location.Substring(0, location.IndexOf(",", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
                }
                return location;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.ErrorFormat("Error in Link Data Repository {0} in Parse Links {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

And small simple table:

```
       <table id="detailTabTable" width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="detailTabContentLt">Current List Price:</td>
                <td class="detailTabContentPriceRt">
                  <span class="aiDetailCurrentPrice">AED 6,600,000</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="detailTabContentLt" style="white-space: nowrap;">Plot size (Sq. Ft.):</td>
                <td class="detailTabContentRt">N/A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="detailTabContentLt" valign="top">Locality</td>
                <td class="detailTabContentRt">Dubai, Dubai</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Your sample HTML does not have tbody mentioned in the XPath....

Comment: This Xpath I got from the Chrome developer tool automatically. But you're right, I should try without that tag

Comment: If you get this XPath query from chrome, there must be another html code than you've shown us. Please update your html code so we may be able to help you!

Comment: Unfortunately, when I remove tbody tag I got same result.

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz, there is huge html page, so where exactly should I look for "another" html?

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested your code. As mentioned in the comments when you do **remove** `tbody` from your xpath expression everything works fine. This worked fine for 
me.

```
private static void htmlAgilityPackTest()
{
    string html = " <table id=\"detailTabTable\" width=\"99%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tr><td class=\"detailTabContentLt\">Current List Price:</td><td class=\"detailTabContentPriceRt\"><span class=\"aiDetailCurrentPrice\">AED 6,600,000</span></td> </tr><tr> <td class=\"detailTabContentLt\" style=\"white-space: nowrap;\">Plot size (Sq. Ft.):</td><td class=\"detailTabContentRt\">N/A</td></tr> <tr><td class=\"detailTabContentLt\" valign=\"top\">Locality</td> <td class=\"detailTabContentRt\">Dubai, Dubai</td> </tr> <tr><td colspan=\"2\"></td> </tr>  </table>";
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    document.LoadHtml(html);

    var node = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='detailTabTable']/tr[3]/td[2]");
    string location = GetLocation(node);
    Console.WriteLine("Location: " + location);
}
```

In case I misunderstood anything please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fizzler and select stuff the CSS way :)
http://blog.simontimms.com/2014/02/24/parsing-html-in-c-using-css-selectors/